# Why I get different value for my variable? (C++)

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks

Why I get different value for "k" variable when I add something to the end of my code. The k's value is 4 but if I add that little part in the comment it changes to 5. I guess that shouldnt affect anything. Am I wrong? Or what can I do to solve this annyoying problem?

My code (Code:blocks)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int N = 10;
int A[]={1100, 700, 950, 780, 850, 1050, 750, 950, 950, 700};

int k = 0;
 if (A[0] > 800) { 
    k = 1;
} else {
    k = 0;
}
for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
    if (A[i]<= 800 && A[i+1] > 800) {
        k++;
    }
}
cout << k << endl;

/* int max_size = k;
int h[max_size]; */
}
```

Comment: This code has undefined behaviour - access to the A array ouside of it's bounds.

Comment: Arrays are indexed from `0` to `size - 1` in c++, return to your textbook.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, OP probably knows that. I believe, loops starts at 1 since A[0] is already checked.

Comment: The code in the commented out block that defines the array is not legal C++.

Comment: @SergeyA Well, `A[i+1]` accesses still out of bounds of that range I've been showing, not?

Comment: In case,   "undefined behavior" means writing to the stack memory that either occupies or overlaps the address of the variable declared after `A` in your code.

Comment: You could compile and run your code with the appropriate compiler flags to catch errors like this at runtime (forces a crash). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection#GNU_Compiler_Collection_.28GCC.29

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Undefined behaviour

> In computer programming, undefined behavior (UB) is the result of executing computer code written in a programming language for which the language specification does not prescribe how that code should be handled. Undefined behavior is unpredictable and a frequent cause of software bugs.

Consider this piece of code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
    if (A[i]<= 800 && A[i+1] > 800) {
        k++;
    }
}
```

When `i` is equal to `N - 1`, the condition inside the loop becomes:

```
if (A[N-1]<= 800 && A[N] > 800)
```

the result of which results to [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You could solve this by changing the limit in the for which is probably what you wanted in the first case:

```
for (int i = 1; i < N - 1; i++)
```

or by changing the condition inside the loop to this:

```
if (A[i - 1]<= 800 && A[i] > 800)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (A[i]<= 800 && A[i+1] > 800)
```

`A[i+1]` is out of range when `i=N-1`

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: because it's undefined behavior so anything can happen, including the problem Hackensack is having

Comment: Do you mean this answer is UB? "How do I resolve this?" and "it is out of range", to me, doesn't fit.

Comment: "don't use any index that is out of range". it's the answer for the question

Comment: To be clear 3 questions were asked. The main question is "Why I get different value for my variable?", the answer to which is "because your code has undefined behavior"

Comment: @Kevin that isn't in this "answer" either! ivan: May I suggest that you add that to your answer so that it becomes complete?

Comment: you have different values, because  there is different data in the computer memory after A-array, when you have different code. I think your program accesses max_size variable when you uncomment the code, and  when the code is commented, your program accesses unused memory.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the answer provided by @ivan, the problem is with incorrect indexing. So, the correct way is..

```
for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
    if (A[i-1]<= 800 && A[i] > 800) {
        k++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what the code is supposed to accomplish, but the most reasonable guess at that implies you should fix both the undefined behavior and a separate incorrect behavior by changing:

```
if (A[i]<= 800 && A[i+1] > 800) {
```

to

```
if (A[i-1]<= 800 && A[i] > 800) {
```